# How to draw Paint In Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a program that draw line in Java, I used PaintComponent but I didn't know why it doesn't work. The below code I've wrote so far. Please help me. I created JFrame in other class.

```
package Paint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MousePanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean start;
    private Point last;
    private ArrayList<Point> lines;

    public MousePanel() {
        start = false;
        lines = new ArrayList<Point>();
        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == e.BUTTON1) {
                start = true;
                last = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                lines.add(last);
            }
            if (e.getButton() == e.BUTTON3)
                start = false;
        }
    }

    private class MouseMotionHandler extends MouseMotionAdapter {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            if (start) {
                last = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                lines.add(last);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.setColor(Color.black);
           // draw all lines
           if (lines.size()<2) return;
           Point firstPoint = (Point)lines.get(0);
           Point secondPoint;
           for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++){
              secondPoint = (Point) lines.get(i);
              g.drawLine(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y,            secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y);
              firstPoint = secondPoint;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: `I created JFrame in other class` - so where is the code? Until a problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't relevant to the problem. For example we don't know how you add the panel to the frame. Maybe the problem is the layout manager? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Maybe the problem is that you don't override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Also, you're not placing an `@Override` on `paintComponent`, which you would need for it to replace the default (`JPanel`) method call.

Comment: package Paint;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo extends JFrame {
 public Demo() {
     setTitle("MouseEvent Test");
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     getContentPane().add(new MousePanel());
     setSize(300,200);
     setVisible(true);
   }

}
This is a JFram class, i think it's like normal , so i didn't post here

Comment: Thank you very much for advise, i have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mousePressed` and `mouseDragged` instead of `mouseClicked` and `mouseMoved`. I have re-factored your code. Hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MousePanel extends JPanel {

    private boolean start;
    private Point last;
    private ArrayList<Point> lines;

    public MousePanel() {
        start = false;
        lines = new ArrayList<Point>();
        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                start = true;
                last = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                lines.add(last);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                start = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (start) {
                last = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                lines.add(last);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        // draw all lines
        if (lines.size() < 2) {
            return;
        }
        Point firstPoint = (Point) lines.get(0);
        Point secondPoint;
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            secondPoint = (Point) lines.get(i);
            g.drawLine(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y);
            firstPoint = secondPoint;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that:  `private ArrayList<Point> lines;` would best be `private ArrayList<Line2D> lines;` - though I note you are sticking to the logic displayed in the OP.